# Calculating the Probability of a Subset

Tags: probability, probability-theory, python

This is my first time facing a topic in stochastics.

My Problem: i have a total set of 7000 Numbers and a fixed subset containing 450 Numbers. So let's assume Numbers from 1-450 are red, Numbers from 451-7000 are blue. So now my question is: If i guess 3 random numbers (numbers cannot be the same) what is the probability that I guess a red number? 
Guessing correct would be p = 450/7000, right? So trying this 3 times should give me the probability of 3 * 450/7000, but this would lead to 100% correctness at 16 tries, which seems not to be correct. I should only reach 100% correctness after 6551 tries.

Could anybody explain me how to calculate my problem? Maybe even explaining the formula to me?

Best Regards,

Korbi

**EDIT**: After further research and the help here I found an actual formula targeting my problem called [Hypergeometric Distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution). This is exactly what i want to calculate and plot.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First we do the probability that you guess three blue numbers:
$$
\frac{6550}{7000}
$$
for the first number to be blue, then
$$
\frac{6549}{6999}
$$
for the second number to be blue, then
$$
\frac{6548}{6998}
$$
for the third number to be blue.  Thus,
$$
\frac{6550}{7000}\;\frac{6549}{6999}\;\frac{6548}{6998}
$$
is the probability of getting three blue.  The complement
$$1 - \frac{6550}{7000}\;\frac{6549}{6999}\;\frac{6548}{6998}
$$
is the probability of getting at least one red.  Is that what you mean by "guessing red"?

Comment: But the probability of guessing blue should be 6550/7000 right? Since there are only 450 reds and 6550 blues

Yes. At least one red, as far as i've understood my problem

Comment: Right, I will correct.

Answer (score 1):

Try to compute the probability of **not** guessing any red numbers first.

Comment: So this would be p = 1-(450/7000)³ right?

Comment: @koapsi not quite. If you are drawing with replacement, it would be $$1 - \left(1 - \frac{450}{7000}\right)^3,$$ but since you are likely drawing without replacement, you need to construct these probabilities separately for every step...